# What type to use for a dictionary-like object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In TypeScript, I sometimes have functions which expect (or return) objects, where those objects are treated as dictionaries. Basically my question is: what is the correct type to use here?

I could use

```
Record<string, any>
```

but I nowhere found this suggested. Instead, everyone suggests to use

```
{ [ key: string ]: any }
```

but if I do so and later try to access a property, it is of type any, but it should be any | undefined. IOW, this type suggests that for *any* given key there will be a value (which of course is wrong).

We for now ended up to create our own Dictionary type:

```
type Dictionary<K extends string, T> = {
  [key in K]?: T;
}
```

However, this seems to be overhead for what we want to achieve, given that this should be a pretty common requirement.

Of course one could also just use

```
{}
```

but this then also allows arrays, which is not wanted.

How do you solve this correctly?

PS: Another option may be to use

```
{ [ key: string ]: any | undefined }
```

but again this seems cumbersome.

PPS: The examples aren’t perfect since any of course includes undefined. Think of any other type here, e.g. a dictionary for numbers.

Comment: Just a side note... using default-constructed objects as dictionaries is dangerous, unless for example you don't mind that all your dictionaries contain the key `"constructor"`.

Comment: `Record`'s actual definition is pretty close to what everyone suggests using. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html (I can't deep link that page, so just search "Record")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to have at least two parts, so trying to answer them separately:

The type `{ [ key: string ]: any }` is usually correct and the values don't need to be written as `any | undefined`, because the `any` type is parent of `undefined`, so `any | undefined` reduces to just `any` in the end.

Then as Tyler pointed out in comments, your type `Dictionary` covers a common use case, which is why it's implemented almost exactly like this in the standard library as `Record`. So yes, it's a common requirement, and that is a common answer to it.

Comment: As said in my PPS, the example with `any` was a little bit unfortunate, but think of a dictionary for numbers: The `number | undefined` is definitely something else than just `number`. So, to cut a long story short, if I get your answer correctly it is: Use `Record` if you want to ensure that you may get `undefined` back, otherwise use the index signature?

Comment: Indeed. I'm now unsure what level of genericity you want to achieve. Could you provide an example of code on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ on a case that bothers you ?

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCGAbAphAXDA3gbRga2QE8NoAnASzAHMYBdDMAVwFsAjZUmAXxgF4sAUDGEx4GAKwBmAEwAaISNYYA7AE4AHPJExgGaQDYALAK4BuAQNCQQKAHSIQVABQIUEW-ACU5qxBvJ7RxckVFsAE28gA … why is `sales.a` and `sales.d` detected as `number`? Shouldn't this be `number | undefined` (since the compiler can't know whether `a` and `d` actually exist)?

Comment: PS: I think I have wrapped up my thoughts on this in a new question, so maybe it makes more sense to discuss the answers there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337747/trying-to-understand-index-signatures-in-typescript