# Why does TypeScript allow checking against undefined?

Tags: typescript

In the following example the variable `boolOrNull` is never undefined and the condition always true, why does TypeScript not complain?

```
let boolOrNull: boolean | null = null;
if (boolOrNull !== undefined) {
    console.log(123);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting Ryan Cavanaugh from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11920):

> We intentionally allow this for the sake of defensive programming (i.e. defending against missing inputs from non-TS code). If there's enough demand we could add a flag or something.

That is, if your Typescript code ever has to interact with non-Typescript code, you may want to check that the non-Typescript code doesn't provide an `undefined` or `null` value where it isn't supposed to.

Of course, with the `strictNullChecks` flag enabled, Typescript code won't allow `undefined` to occur here, unless other unsafe code is used like [accessing a missing property on a type with an index signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57337747/12299000). However, one of Typescript's design principles is that it should accommodate idiomatic Javascript code, and it's fairly normal for Javascript programmers to compare values with `undefined` or `null` even when those values aren't supposed to ever be `undefined` or `null`.

As the quote above suggests, if a compiler flag enabling stricter checks like this would be useful to you, you could reply to the linked GitHub issue to give your feedback about it.